# What value to use for numHashTable in Spark LSH by Uber?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, locality-sensitive-hash, minhash

I'm trying to use `.approxSimilarityJoin` of Spark MLlib LSH: [MinHash for Jaccard Distance](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#minhash-for-jaccard-distance) e.g.

```
val mh = new MinHashLSH()
    .setNumHashTables(5)
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setOutputCol("hashes")
```

I understand that the higher the numHashTables, the more accurate the system, and the more complex/slow the calculation. I have two questions about the parameters:

- What's the relationship between numHashTables and the MinHash fingerprint size?
- How do I set the value correctly?

NOTE: I believe that the algorithm has been added to MLlib by Uber: https://eng.uber.com/lsh/

Comment: This is the old question but just to answer your second part of the question quickly, the value you'll need to set is a compromise between your computational resources and the accuracy of your model. Think of it as if you are comparing Precision and Recall.

Answer (score 0):

I think numHashTables is just the MinHash fingerprint size.
numHashTables may be a experience parameter, It depends on your scene, and b * r =  numHashTables (r=1,recently)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).